# c language ask a triangle formula

Tags: c

Write a program that outputs the length of the sides of the possible triangle and the number of triangles, when you want to create a triangle by inputting the sum of the lengths of the three sides of the triangle.(the three sides are integer variables.)
(the sum of the lengths of the two sides of the triangles is greater than the length of the other side)

For example:

```
Sum of three sides: 6

 1 3 2\n
 2 2 2\n
 2 3 1\n
 3 1 2\n
 3 2 1\n


number of triangle: 5
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, count=0;
    int sum = a + b + c;


    printf("Sum of three sides: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &sum);

    for (a = 1; a < sum; a++)
        for (b = 1; b < sum; b++)
            for (c = 1; c < sum; c++)

                if (a + b > c && a+b+c==sum)

                    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\n", a, b, c);


                    printf("number of triangle: %d", count );

}
```

I don't know how to output the number of triangles and how to put
 "the sum of the lengths of the two sides of the triangles is greater than the length of the other side" into code.

`4 1 1` is not a valid triangle. `a + b > c` is the triangle formula.

Comment: `count` isn't going to modify *itself* if the intent is to count the number of successful tests.

Comment: Curly braces, and indentation.

Comment: Attention to the starting value of the inner loops to prevent duplicate solutions, for example when `sum` is 12, to prevent finding all the permutions of 3, 4, 5.

Comment: To me the "solution" 1 3 2 seems to make a real bad triangle

Comment: The proper term for that is a "degenerate triangle."

Comment: The formula is not : `a + b > c` but `a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > d`!

Comment: It's the Triangle Inequality Theorem. The sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side

Comment: @Swordfish No, logical and is correct as all 3 must be true. However the last in the comment says: `.. && a + c > d` but it should be `b` instead of `d`. Just a minor typo....

Comment: @4386427, when dyslexia hit.

Comment: @4386427 Saw my error after writing my comment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not increment the `count` variable at any place. It just lies there unchanged throughout. Also, you are checking for the validity of just one side and not for the satisfaction of conditions for all sides.

And also, your **sample output is wrong**, **[1 3 2], [2 3 1], [3 1 2], [3 2 1]**, etc are **not** valid triangles. Only [2,2,2] satisfies the triangle condition. **Please cross check the expected output before posting it as a requirement here.**

here is a possible working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, count=0;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Sum of three sides: ");
    scanf("%d", &sum);

    while(a < sum) {
      b=1;
        while(b < sum) {
          c=1;
            while(c < sum) {
                if ((a+b+c == sum)&&(a+b>c)&&(a+c>b)&&(c+b>a))
                {
                  count+=1;
                  printf("Triangle %d:\nSide 1: %d   Side 2: %d   Side 3: %d\n\n", count, a, b, c);
                }
              c++;
            }
          b++;
        }
      a++;
    }
    printf("Possible number of triangles: %d", count );
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out in comments/answers the main problem is that your code only checks for `a + b > c` where it should for **all combination** of "sum of two sides being larger than the last side".

Besides that there is no reason for using 3 loops. When `a` and `b` is selected by the outer two loops, `c` can be calculated like `c = sum - a - b`. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a, b, c, count=0;
    int sum;

    printf("Sum of three sides: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &sum);

    for (a = 1; a < sum; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b < sum; b++)  
        {
            c = sum - a - b;
            if (c < 1) break; // No reason to continue so break out of inner loop

            if ((a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (b + c > a))
            {
                printf("%d\t %d\t %d\n", a, b, c);
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("number of triangle: %d", count );
    return 0;
}
```

You can improve the program performance further by considering the condition for the loops:

```
    for (a = 1; a < sum; a++)
```

Is it really necessary to continue all the way to `sum - 1` ?

Can there ever be a triangle where `a` is greater or equal to `sum/2` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the condition for all three sides and you have to increment `count` for a successful test.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, count=0;
    int sum = a + b + c;

    printf("Sum of three sides: ");
    scanf("%d", &sum);

    for (a = 1; a < sum; a++)
        for (b = 1; b < sum; b++)
            for (c = 1; c < sum; c++)
                if ((a+b+c==sum) && ((a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (c + b > a)))
                {
                    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\n", a, b, c);
                    count++;
                }
    printf("number of triangles: %d", count );
}
```

Output:

```
Sum of three sides: 6
2        2       2
number of triangle(s): 1


Sum of three sides: 7
1        3       3
2        2       3
2        3       2
3        1       3
3        2       2
3        3       1
number of triangle(s): 6
```

Comment: Only 2 *different* triangles for `sum == 7`.

Comment: The values of sides a, b and c differ. I did not know if he wanted totally unique triangles.

Comment: From the exemple it's kinda ok. As OP print 5 result for sum=6.

Comment: For clearly a beginner, I do not encourage giving the complete answer as now he/she didn't learn anything.

Comment: This is the first question he asked. So some leeway... :).  Anyway, I wrote the conditions he had to check and to increment the counter. Rest of his code is okay.

Answer (score 0):

The condition ((a+b+c==sum) && ((a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (c + b > a))) may be improoved by adding && a<=b && b<=c to avoid the generation of dublicate triangles. for example, 3 3 1 is the same as 3 1 3 and 1 3 3.
(P.s I put this as an answer because I do not have enough reputation to post a comment. )